# Compute annual mean of overlapping cells using daily rasters

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, numpy

I am stuck at somewhat simple looking calculation. I have daily temperature rasters from 2001 to 2014 with following name format:

```
`2001001`
`2001002`
 |
 |
 `2014365`
```

I want to compute annual mean rasters using overlapping cells of same years. How do I insert all rasters from same year as a list of rasters into the `numpy.mean` at the end of following? Any suggestions to get annual mean rasters would be appreciative.

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Define time duration to handle leap years
#**************************************************
time = []
start_date = datetime.datetime(2001,1,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2012,12,31)
step = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
while start_date < end_date:
    time.append(start_date.strftime('%Y%j'))
    start_date += step

time = [int(i) for i in time]

# Convert rasters to numpy array and compute mean
#**************************************************
annual = numpy.zeros((1200,1200))
for ii in time:
    ras = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(file_path + str(ii))
    tt = time[ii]
    if ii == 0:
        year_old = tt[0:4]
        index_start = ii
    else:
        year = tt[0:4]
        if year != year_old:
            year_mean = np.mean([index_start:ii],axis=0)
```

Comment: What is the raster size and shape? Have you managed to get a list of rasters by year using the slicing method? It might be worthwhile creating an numpy (np) array of zeros (see np.zeros) the exact size and shape of the expected input arrays.   Convert the arrays one at a time and add them incrementally using the += inplace operator to conserve memory and add them in sequence to the zeros array. Sum/N = avg or check out incremental averaging (assuming you have no nodata values).  If your data have nodata values check out np.nansum and np.nanmean as alternatives

Comment: ps from numpy impot *   is spelled incorrectly and highly discouraged... use   import numpy as np   in that way you always know that np.mean is different than mean in python

Comment: Can you not add the rasters and divide by the number of input rasters to calculate average cell values? Either the Plus tool (two at a time) or Raster Calculator (all at a time by building an expression) should do it; note: Raster Calculator has a limit of 4096 characters in its expression, I know that sounds like a lot but once you put together the full paths of a dozen rasters it starts to look a little smaller.

Comment: do you have enough memory to hold all rasters at the same time?

Comment: do you want a mean per pixel? or simply an overal mean?

Comment: I need mean per pixel and Dan's suggestion is useful to compute one at a time rather loading all raters at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's some untested code that should give you close to what you're after.
two main things...
-make big empty numpy array and fill it one raster at a time
EDIT...no surprise...big array didn't fit.
-also store a year numpy array for easy masking of years.
some suggestions in comments as I went.

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Define time duration to handle leap years
#**************************************************
times = []    ####change! time is a bad variable name!
years = []    # a list to store just the year, same order as times.
start_date = datetime.datetime(2001,1,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2012,12,31)
step = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
while start_date < end_date:
    times.append(start_date.strftime('%Y%j'))
    years.append(int(start_date.strftime('%Y'))  #store the years in a list
    start_date += step

###time = [int(i) for i in time]  ## keep as string
times = np.array(times)
years = np.array(years)  ##make into numpy arrays for easy masking

# Convert rasters to numpy array and compute mean
#**************************************************


#now loop through unique years that you have
for yr in np.unique(years):
    year_times = times[years == yr] #mask only times you need

    #your 'big' raster is now just a year's worth of data
    year_rasters = numpy.zeros((year_times.shape[0], 1200, 1200))
    for count in range(year_times.shape[0]):
        f_name = file_path + year_times[count]
        year_rasters[count,:,:] = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(f_name) 

    yr_mean = np.mean(year_rasters, axis=0) 
    np.save('mean_temp_' + str(yr) + '.npy', yr_mean)
```

another small suggestion if the only files you have in your raster folder are the ones you want to load, use glob and parse the file names. This would guard against the possibility of missing a file and throwing an error (which I didn't account for...but you should!).

Comment: It gives `ValueError: array is too big`. Maybe array in chunks would work. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: not surprised.  you could have simply tried to initialize a big array in the first place to see if you had the memory capacity.  see edits.  if you still don't have the memory, you'll need to implement a running average which will be a pretty simple change from the current code. you're welcome.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. The only issue is that I am dealing with missing files.

Comment: @ibe I would do a quick check then just before the line **times.append(start_date.strftime('%Y%j'))**  something like **if os.path.isfile(fname): continue**  see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python